# Is it OK to put a paper on the arXiv after it has been published online?

Tags: publications, arxiv

Suppose that a paper has just got online in a journal without any previous submission to the arXiv. But the authors have spotted some minor typos and are also not satisfied with the typesetting of the online version. Can they put a newer version of the paper on the arXiv that contains some typesetting edits and minor corrections of typos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will depend on the terms and conditions that the journal published the paper under (and theoretically on the legal systems of the US and whichever country the journal publisher operates from). These conditions could range anywhere from "the publisher now owns the copyright, and you can't publish the paper anywhere in any form without their say so", to "put their typeset version up online anywhere you like". These terms should have been included or linked to when you signed for the final publication.

On average though, provided the publisher is willing for you to put out preprints, they typically *want* it to be your last version, not their typeset version, in which case there isn't likely to be any additional issue with the kind of differences you appear to be talking about.

Comment: What does _last version_ mean? Does it mean the latest version (the version the OP wants to put online)?

Comment: @user2768 That's actually a slightly complicated question. In theory it might mean the version that the editor said yes to before the copy editing process, but If you want to see a flavour of the range of possibilities, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_journals_by_preprint_policy

Comment: So assuming the journal does not have any issue with uploading to preprint servers, you are saying that it is OK to do this?

Comment: @origimbo is correct. Check the license that the authors should have signed before the journal published. A journal being ok with preprint posting may not be ok with the final copy being uploaded. The final copy would be what the journal actually published online (usually with logos). If the authors made minor changes to the preprint version, arXiv is probably acceptable. However, this completely depends on the license agreement.

Comment: @H.R. It does depend a bit on the wording of the licence. If the journal allows you to put up something like "the accepted version" and you take the opportunity to turn a "hte" or two into "the" at the same time, while using your own page layout, that'll be fine ethically and probably legally (note, I'm not a lawyer and that's not legal advice), not least since the journal won't check that hard. On the other hand, don't change the title, or make massive changes to notation, since people will still be citing (and quoting) from the actual journal paper.